# Having trouble displaying custom webface font

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I have some custom icons that I want to use as a webface font:

[image]

However, I can't seem to get them displayed.. All I get to see is the corresponding letter ('a' and 'f'). As shown [here](http://liveweave.com/25Ue7e) You'll also see the working example of the font 'socialico'

Comment: Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Use @font-face  In the past I had lots of troubles with font-face but if you type it out right it works fine:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Custom Font Name';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(linktofont.com/font.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Replace "Custom Font Name" with what you would like your font to be named when using CSS.  and replace "linktofont.com/font.ttf" with the path to the font.

**`EDIT`**
Sorry, I read that wrong, I found the problem.  If you look at your @import

```
@import url (http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sc4rCApa);
```

You have a space between "url" and your path, so reaplace it with:

```
@import url(http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=sc4rCApa);
```

Comment: Sorry, I rushed it, but it's still not working.. If I copy and paste that code into jsfiddle.net, you'll still see the letters only..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - and all my syntax was correct.  I was instructed by a friend that it may be the font itself that was broken or incorrect.  Here's how it was resolved:

(1) Used original font downloaded from fontfabric.com
(2) Went to www.fontsquirrel.com to generate a new font kit... including the css
(3) Uploaded fonts generated from FontSquirrel
(4) Replaced my CSS with the css generated from FontSquirrel for the @font-face section
(5) Updated the name of the font that is called for later in the CSS

and that was it.... worked like a charm!